# SQL IF statement convert to text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement as below:

```
SELECT 
 b.pricedate AS [Price Quote Date]
,b.jobid AS [Job No.]
,a.priceid AS [Price Quote Id]
,b.headline AS [Price Quote Title]
,a.activitytext AS [Activity Text]
,a.tnum AS [No. of Hours]
,a.tsale AS [Hourly Rate]
,b.stat AS [PQ Status]
FROM JobPriceactivity a
                        INNER JOIN JobPrice AS b ON a.priceid = b.priceid
WHERE a.Activitytext LIKE '%influencer%' and jobid >= '700000'and jobid <= '709999'
ORDER BY b.jobid
```

which gives me the below sample:

[image]

Is it possible to use an IF statement within my original select statement to look at the PQ status and change the code to a more meaningful text?

For example:  IF PQ Status = 50 then convert to 'approved'

any advice or help much appreciated.

Comment: A `CASE` statement is what you're looking for.

Comment: what do you need where Status  not equal to 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `case when`

```
b.pricedate AS [Price Quote Date]
,b.jobid AS [Job No.]
,a.priceid AS [Price Quote Id]
,b.headline AS [Price Quote Title]
,a.activitytext AS [Activity Text]
,a.tnum AS [No. of Hours]
,a.tsale AS [Hourly Rate]
,case when b.stat=50 then 'approved' 
else 'not approved'  end AS [PQ Status]
FROM JobPriceactivity a
                        INNER JOIN JobPrice AS b ON a.priceid = b.priceid
WHERE a.Activitytext LIKE '%influencer%' and jobid >= '700000'and jobid <= '709999'
ORDER BY b.jobid
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN b.stat = 50 THEN 'Approved' ELSE b.stat END AS [PQ Status]
```